# WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'cucumber' failed to discover tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, junit5

While running Cucumber Test i am getting below error and not test gets executed. Please help totally stucked. Build is success full but with warning and while executing getting same error.

```
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'cucumber' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/gherkin/Named
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.FeatureResolver.resolveFeature(FeatureResolver.java:218)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.FeatureResolver.resolvePackageResource(FeatureResolver.java:154)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.FeatureResolver.resolveClass(FeatureResolver.java:144)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolve(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:40)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:25)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.CucumberTestEngine.discover(CucumberTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:168)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.TestPlanScannerFilter.accept(TestPlanScannerFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.scanClasspath(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.core.gherkin.Named
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
Specifically the bit about "Help others reproduce the problem". For example which version of Cucumber are you using? What does your project look like? Ect.

Comment: And in this case I would guess your depencies are not correct.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje yes you are right, it has been resolved. I was using lower version of Cocumber 5.x.x, after updateting it to 6.x.x it fixed the issue. 'I will take care and update the question.